# Using AppFabric DashBoard from my .Net Application

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7, appfabric, dashboard

Is there any api which I can use from my c# application to manipulate the information that the appFabric dashboard provides??

For example accesing the information of the dashboard from my website so I can give much more information about the state of the proceses, wcf fails, etc??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Imo you'd have to dig into persistence and monitoring database schemas to understand and then build your own API. It would mainly rely on queries requesting these databases.

Appfabric on IIS is a UI for monitoring wcf services, it obviously seems to rely on queries against these databases. It can retrive idle, failed or in progress calls to your services.

App fabric dashboard also provides details with "where" SQL predicates. You can freely inspire from these to make your own API/UI.